# Constraint formation help

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, vehicle-routing

I am implementing a quay crane optimization model. The objective is to minimize the loading time.

Inputs to the model are
$I=$ number of nodes
$K =$ number of cranes
$z_k =$ crane speed in meter/minutes
$p_{ik}$ = processing time of crane $k$ at node $i$ in minutes
$L_k=$ Loading rate in tonnes/minutes of crane $k$
$D=$ distance matrix for nodes $i$ and $j$

Variables used are
$X_{ijk} =1$ if the crane $k$ follows the arc $i-j$, $0$ otherwise.

Is there a way to implement a constraint that identifies the loading is complete by all the cranes at any time. For example, after 20 minutes, 45 minutes, or 100 minutes.

[Link to the problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.00527)

Comment: In the paper you linked, the authors use the variable $W$ to denote the makespan of the schedule. The makespan of a schedule is exactly what you are asking for: the moment when all tasks are completed. If this is not what you are asking for, could you clarify your question?

Comment: Also, could you make the title of your question more descriptive?